# Definition ambiguity about whether dereference operator yields object vs value in an expression

Tags: c++

Recently, I have started learning C++ and following the first book from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) StackOverflow resource. My question is pretty straight forward. The way `*` (in an expression) is defined as in the three current resources I am referring to learn C++ are as follows.

`*` in this context is the dereference operator.

1. C++ Primer says `*` yields an object.
2. Wikipedia says `*` returns an l-value equivalent to the value at the pointer address.
3. A Tour of C++ says `*` returns the content of object.

Where, `2` and `3` make complete sense to me but not `1`. Can someone dumb it down for me?

In my understanding an object is simply a memory location which holds some value.
However, Can object be thrown as keyword to reflect the value in context to dereferencing a pointer as in `1`?

Examples are greatly appreciated.

Edit: Solved, Answers by user `eerorika` and `bolov` are perfect and elegant. However `eerorika` answered first so I will accept it as the answer but all the answers are great as well in their own way. Thanks SO community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colloquially, and in this context in particular, value and object are often used as synonyms.

All three descriptions are correct. Wikipedia one is the most precise description out of those three.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue) says of values:

> An lvalue refers to an **object** that persists beyond a single expression. An rvalue is a temporary value that does not persist beyond the expression that uses it.

C++ standard (draft) says of objects:

> The constructs in a C ++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. An object is
>   created by a definition (6.1), by a new-expression (8.3.4), when implicitly changing the active member of a
>   union (12.3), or when a temporary object is created (7.4, 15.2). An object occupies a region of storage in its
>   period of construction (15.7), throughout its lifetime (6.8), and in its period of destruction (15.7). ...

And about memory location:

> A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having
>   nonzero width. ...

---

> In my understanding an object is simply a memory location which holds some value which can be useful or null

An object cannot be *null* in general - unless that object is a pointer, or some other specific type which has a special value described by the word null.

Comment: On Point. This is the exact answer I have been looking for. Also, may I dare ask you to suggest a personally preferred resource to learn C++? Just one please.

Comment: @Jash There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) C++ book list, that you can check out.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I mentioned above in my question I know the list and I am currently on the first book. But that question is specifically for eerorika. Thanks btw. :)

Comment: @Jash Then such a question is primarily-opinion-based. That list, at the very least, was deemed good enough by majority of community. Personal preferences, are, in my opinion, irrelevant. If person A likes (prefers) book X, doesn't meant that person B would like (prefer) it as well.

Comment: @Angew Oops, didn't see that. :/ But, still, that page is the first thing that comes to mind when someone asks for C++ resources, so I auto-typed that comment.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Ofcourse the comment is primarily-opinion-based because it only asks for the opinion of the user eerorika because there are answers but his answer caught the essence of my question and addresses it. Although the question is not. User Bolov below answers it quite elegantly as well.

Comment: @Jash I think we used one of Bjarne's books in the C++ course I took a decade ago. The book list is probably better source than me.

Comment: @eerorika Lol Bjarne has a couple books now but I get it. Thanks! I hope you have a great holidays. This doubt was driving me nuts. Now I can rest for the day. ;)

Answer (score 3):

In C++ terminology, an "object" is a value which occupies a region of storage. Here are examples of objects:

```
int x = 42; // x is an object of type int
int y; // y is an object of type int
char *p = new char; // p points to an object of type char
size_t s = std::string().size(); // s is an object of type size_t; there is also an unnamed temporary object of type std::string involved in the expression
```

Dereferencing a pointer yields an lvalue which refers to the object to which the point points. So let's take another example:

```
int i = 42;
int *p = &i;
*p = 314;
```

The expression `*p` is an lvalue which references the object `i`. After the above code, `i` will have the value 314.

So I'd say that both statements 1 (C++ Primer) and 2 (Wikipedia) are correct, saying the same thing in different words. While 3 is probably correct as well, I consider it somewhat misleading, as you don't normally say an object to have "contents." You could say an object has a value, or that it is a value.

---

Regarding this statement which was originally present in the question:

> In my understanding an object is simply a memory location which holds some value which can be useful or null.

The first part is effectively correct, an object is a memory location which holds some value. However, the second part seems somewhat confused: in C++, you normally speak about null only in the context of pointers. A pointer is a type of object which holds an address of another object (or function), or a special value, the *null pointer value,* which means "not pointing to anything." Most objects (`int`s, `double`s, `char`s, arrays, instances of class types) cannot be said to be "null".

Comment: So the definition by C++ Primer i.e. `1` is correct?

Comment: @jash none of the 3 are wrong.  Some are more precise, or use different terms.

Answer (score 3):

They are all wrong. But that's ok, because they are all correct :)

The only real authority here is the standard. And the standard is very precise:

> §5.3.1 Unary operators [expr.unary.op]
>
> 1 The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which
>   it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or
>   function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression
>   is “pointer to T,” the type of the result is “T.”
>
> [n4296]

So there you go, the only valid definition is:

> the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which
>   the expression points

Anything else is plain wrong.

**Except**... The standard is useful for compiler implementers and settling down debates of code conformity with the standard. When teaching or just when talking about C++ we generally aren't as rigorous as the standard. We do some simplications for the sake of ... well simplicity (or sometimes just out of ignorance). So we sometimes say "object" when the correct standard terminology would be "lvalue expression referring to an object" and so on.

I would say all the definitions are correct, they just use different terms or take different shortcuts for the sake of easy understanding.

Comment: Lol, great answer although that simplicity almost confused me.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Dereference)

> The dereference or indirection expression has the form
>
> `* pointer-expression`
> If `pointer-expression` is a pointer to function, the result of the dereference operator is a function designator for that function.
> If `pointer-expression` is a pointer to object, the result is an lvalue expression that designates the pointed-to object.

So as an example

```
int x = 5;    // x is an lvalue
int* p = &x;  // p is a pointer that points to x
*p = 7;       // dereferencing p returns the lvalue x, which you can then operate on
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's wrong, it's just not specific enough. I think definition 2 in your question is the closest to how I would describe it.

Comment: @Jash It depends on what you call an "object". The term "object" is somewhat ambiguous in C++, since instances of classes/structures are usually called "objects" but it could also mean other things.

Comment: @CoryKramer can you update your answer because your comment answers my question so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you elaborate a bit on what other things it could mean?